# zsh option to generate the recomended options

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, zsh, archlinux

There is a nice option when setting up `zsh` on Ubuntu

```
Populate your ~/.zshrc with the configuration recommended
by the system administrator and exit (you will need to edit
the file by hand, if so desired).
```

However, on a fresh Arch Linux install the option is missing. Is there a way to have it (or maybe, I am being picky here) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you haven't got a `.zshrc` and there's a `/etc/zsh/recommended.zshrc`. If you say yes, it'll just copy that one to `.zshrc`.

Arch, bare-bones awesomesauce that it is, doesn't bother to ship such a file.

Comment: Awesome sauce it is!

Comment: the funny fact is that the installer comes bundled with the zsh :D